# Why is ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID returning 9999999?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS Word document that has the `ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID` return `9999999`.

Even after I set it to US English it still returns `9999999`.

```
ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS

? ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID
 9999999
```

Why is this so and how can I fix this?

Comment: See [Word 2003 VBA LanguageID returns 9999999 or 9](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2e34f4f1-382e-43bb-b5d4-465a736ef990/word-2003-vba-languageid-returns-9999999-or-9?forum=worddev)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not only one language is applied in that document. Usually, when values like this occur in VBA, it is probably a complex problem, a multiple situation, a hodgepodge, or a miscellaneous set.

Yes, my guess is correct, see:
[image]

When I select both Chinese and English, I can see the value 9999999 in the Immediate Pane or the Immediate Window.

Shown in pane 1033 is English(us), and 1028 is Chinese when I select them respectively.

Now that you know this, you can use at least two methods to find out what the [LanguageID property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.languageid) values are for each part of the text

1. use [StoryRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/vba/api/word.storyranges) object, if the different language is on the different story range in a document.
2. use related [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) objects like [Paragraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphs) or [Sentences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.sentences) object to exam each paragraph or sentence,etc. not only the range of [Document.Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/vba/api/word.document.content).

It would be something like:

```vb
Sub FindMultilingualRanges_Why_is_ActiveDocumentContentLanguageID_retutrning_9999999()
    Dim rng As Range, d As Document, sec As Section, _
        p As Paragraph, snt As Sentences, sp As Range
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    Rem exam the Language in each StoryRange
    For Each rng In d.StoryRanges
        If examLanguageID(rng) Then
            GoSub examEverySection
        End If
    Next rng
    
    MsgBox "done!" '"There is only one language in this file"
Exit Sub

    
examEverySection:
    Rem exam the Language in each Section
    For Each sec In rng.Sections
        If examLanguageID(sec.Range) Then
            GoSub examEveryParagraph
        End If
    Next sec
    Return
examEveryParagraph:
    Rem exam the Language in each Paragraph
    For Each p In sec.Range.Paragraphs
        If examLanguageID(p.Range) Then
            GoSub examEverySentence
        End If
    Next p
    Return
examEverySentence:
    Rem do it by yourself,just  like the previous code
    Rem ...
    Return
examEveryShape:
    Rem do it by yourself,just  like the previous code
    Rem ...
    Return
End Sub

Function examLanguageID(rng As Range) As Boolean
    If rng.LanguageID = 9999999 Then
        examLanguageID = True
        rng.Select
        rng.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView rng
        If MsgBox("This range includes a variety of languages" & vbCr & vbCr & vbTab & _
                "Do you want to check it now?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
            End
        End If
    End If
    Selection.Collapse
End Function
```